# External access to symfony 2.1 session

Tags: session, upload, external, symfony-2.1

I use BlueImp file uploader server side with symfony 2.1 as external must-be-lightweight php UploadHandler.php script
I want to get logged user id to use its own directory for uploading
For security reasons it must be done by session, not POST.
in external file when I try session_start(), $_SESSION still empty.
I know how to do it with 1.4:
[Symfony sessions outside app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222227/symfony-sessions-outside-app)
but I have no idea for 2.1

Maybe I am wrong and there is better way to achieve user id in external script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have firewall called `main` in your security.yml config, you should have access to security token (serialized) under `$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security_main']` notice that second key have pattern: `_security_filewallName'

In your case [punkave/symfony2-file-upload-bundle](https://github.com/punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle) can be interesting too.

Comment: thanks, I was trying get this bundle working but without any results, so I wrapped serverside to controller by myself ant that works!